# Android System - app(s) running in background notification

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

Since the O Preview the new notification for apps 'running in the background' has appeared. Originally even Google Play Music fell foul of this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62470721

Google have somehow fixed this in (Google Play Music and Maps at least)

[image]

I have updated my test app to target O and using the new Context.StartForegroundService as per the behaviour change guidelines then  added notification channel to the notification posted in startForeground.

However the 'running in background' notification still appears (including the previously immune Google apps too)

[image]

The behavior documentation makes no reference to this, its reasoning or how to prevent it. Other than not using a service any way to stop it?

Comment: Have your notification importance be higher than the minimum.

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer. I think I'd rather have the two low priority notifications than another visible in the status bar one for every app that needs a foreground service. Seems a strange decision when PRIORITY_MIN fixed the clutter of having to always see Tasker / Facebook Messenger (etc) notifications in the status bar.